# Most efficient method of parsing non-standard XML document in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

In PHP, what is the quickest, most efficient way to parse an XML document formatted like so:

```
<data>
    <rowdata>
        <fieldname>products_id</fieldname>
        <value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
        <fieldname>products_image</fieldname>
        <value><![CDATA[image_one.jpg]]></value>
        <fieldname>products_name</fieldname>
        <value>Product One</value>
    </rowdata>
    <rowdata>
        <fieldname>products_id</fieldname>
        <value><![CDATA[2]]></value>
        <fieldname>products_image</fieldname>
        <value><![CDATA[image_two.jpg]]></value>
        <fieldname>products_name</fieldname>
        <value>Product Two</value>
    </rowdata>
</data>
```

This is the format I've been given by a till system company to import products in to a database. I have no idea why they decided to have `<fieldname>` and `<value>` tags instead of just `<products_id>1</products_id>`

At the moment the only way I can think of doing is writing up some crude loop which sets a boolean each time a `<value>` tag is found and resets

Comment: An xml parser should do that

Comment: An XML parser isn't going to parse this correctly. Tell me how I would access the product_id value using SimpleXML for example?

Comment: An XML Parser will parse this just fine. You're confusing parsing with application logic. There's nothing non-standard about this XML. It's just not laid out the way you prefer.

Comment: @ShaunMcCance Perhaps non-standard was the wrong phrase to use. While this is valid, "standard", XML, it is definitely not semantic so maybe that would've been more appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty straightforward. There is some logic - for each `<fieldname>` there is a `<value>` - I assume that each fieldname correspond to a column in a table.

Using [**simplexml**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) :

```
$xml='<data>
    <rowdata>
        <fieldname>products_id</fieldname>
        <value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
        <fieldname>products_image</fieldname>
        <value><![CDATA[image_one.jpg]]></value>
        <fieldname>products_name</fieldname>
        <value>Product One</value>
    </rowdata>
    <rowdata>
        <fieldname>products_id</fieldname>
        <value><![CDATA[2]]></value>
        <fieldname>products_image</fieldname>
        <value><![CDATA[image_two.jpg]]></value>
        <fieldname>products_name</fieldname>
        <value>Product Two</value>
    </rowdata>
</data>';

$data = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$baseSQL='INSERT into TABLE set ';

foreach($data as $rowdata) {
    $SQL='';
    $count=0;
    foreach ($rowdata->fieldname as $fieldname) {
        if ($SQL!='') $SQL.=',';
        $SQL.=$fieldname.'="'.$rowdata->value[$count].'"';
        $count++;
    }
    echo $baseSQL.$SQL.'<br>';
}
```

produces :

```
INSERT into TABLE set products_id="1",products_image="image_one.jpg",products_name="Product One"
INSERT into TABLE set products_id="2",products_image="image_two.jpg",products_name="Product Two"
```

Comment: Is that the quickest, most efficient way to do it? I need to parse the data in to an associative PHP array, not directly in to the database. Also, the dataset could be MUCH bigger than my exmaple

Comment: The example is illustrative to show how to parse a XML like this, eg associate `fieldname` with correct `value`. This was your problem, as I understood your question. If you want an array, just make an array instead of the SQL - should be easy.

Comment: I didn't actually ask how to do it. I asked what the quickest, most efficent way of doing it was (with the possibility of 50MB+ datasets)

Comment: I think this gives you an answer. It will be reasonably quick. You then have options (assuming you do an array as you say) to save to files using fputcsv etc or write lines to database directly.

Comment: 50mb is nothing to worry about. I do stuff like this all the time, like importing obscure CSV-files in sizes of 200-300mb into databases. The first step is always to get it to work. Then, if you discover performance-problems, you can _begin_ worrying about "the quickest, most efficient" and so on. Guess your client give a damn in whether your import took 12 seconds or 16 seconds :-)

Comment: I agree @davidkonrad. Used similar techniques to build 2,000,00+ insert statements to csv then load data infile. 50MB = Walk in the park

Comment: I appreciate the input from both of you, so please don't think I'm being obtuse, but I'm afraid I can't accept this answer because it does not answer the orignal question. You've given me an answer to how it can be done, which I already knew, and basically told me not to worry about my actual question

Comment: @Andy, not at all! When the answer not meets your requirements, you should never accept it. SO is about good questions that get good answers. Feel free to upvote, downvote or accept any answer you get, there is no pressure forcing you to accept an answer you cannot use.

Comment: @allen213, totally agree. I operate with imports where there can be say 800.000 records, each record with maybe 200 columns. "Normal" or "standard" PHP can easily deal with such amounts of data - using `simplexml` or `fgetcsv` for an instance. What could be faster or more efficient than those standard built in functions in PHP? Maybe something written in perl, or a C++ app runned on desktop.